# How to render multiple html in React Native webview?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, react-native, epub

I'm trying to implement my own Epub reader on React Native.
The problem is how to pass multiple html content files from epub container to webview and render them to make smooth pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrollView` with `pagingEnabled={true}` and with multiple `WebView` as pages

Comment: Not sure it is usefull because epub books have a lot of pages (>1000 pages for iphone)

Comment: you can change `uri`